# JavaScript OnError if image not found or broken

Tags: javascript, datatables

I just use datatables with Javascript. The following code works wonderfull

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
return type === 'display'? 
'<div class="image-plus-text"><img style="width:64px" src="/Minifaces/' + row[0] + ".png" +  '"/>'+ "<br>" + data  + '</div>': data; }
```

If a file/image on the server was not found there is the default "broken-image". 
I tried to extend the img in the following way but its not working (still shows the default broken-image:

```
'<img style="width:64px" src="/Minifaces/' + row[0] + ".png"
OnError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/Minifaces/noimage.png';"/>'+"<br>"+data: data; }
```

Could maybe someone help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: You have `OnError` which is not correct. You need to use `onError`. Also, your quote marks are a bit messy. Consider using [consts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) to work through the logic for the `src` and `onError` before adding them to the tag with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Further, you should not really use `onError` inline at all. Consider reading about [event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Instead of src property, you can try to use data property for dynamic handling. Enjoy and cheers!